# How can I generate unique key using two different numbers and then retrieve this key by using one of these numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, mapping, integer

Having two different numbers I have to generate a unique key. 
For example I have 37 and 8, and by using XOR on them I will get 45, that’s my unique key.
But then I need to retrieve this unique key by using one of those numbers (37 or 8).
So question is, how can I generate unique key using two different numbers and then retrieve this key by using one of these numbers?
It’s allowed to use some third number (mask, key, etc.), but I need a unique key to be really unique.

---

Edit:

All right guys, sorry for probably non clear question.
I have in-memory key-object storage. Memcached for example, no matters.
There I can add some value and specify string key for an object  e.g. Cache.Add(“mykey”, myobj);
But in my app same object have two identifiers, integer and string.
So I want to be able add into cache like this Cache.Add(“mykey”, 1, myobj);
And then to get same cached object by using one of the identifiers. Like this Cache.Get(1) or Cache.Get(“mykey”);
String can be computed into hash, so that’s why I asked about two integers.
My storage is SharedCache ectualy.
I just don’t want to change core of SharedCahce, so probably there is a solution for computing 
key by one of the identifiers.

---

Ok, guys! Thanks for your answers.
But what if use some third static number for computing key/hash. And then use it with one of the identifiers (numbers) for determining the key.
    N1 = 37
    N2 = 8 
    SN3 = 999 (hardcoded)
    key(n1, n2) = key(n1,sn3) = key(n2,sn3)

Also I’m thinking about keeping my identifiers in QWORD. Hash from string identifier is kept in higher DWORD and int identifier is kept in lowest DWORD. Then in methods Cache.Get I can determine type of parameter, if its int so lookup in lower DWORD and if type is string, lookup in higher DWORD.

Comment: What's the maximum range of the input numbers, and the maximum size of the key? (also, check out [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)). And, if the key depends on **two numbers**, it will be impossible to calculate it using one number only. You should rather describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It sounds to me that you may be asking wrong question...

Comment: You're aware that the hash(i.e. `GetHashCode()` of a string is not unique?

Comment: But my string identifiers are unique. Does it make sense?

Comment: As @Groo said, you cannot *compute* the key from one of the numbers. Either you are being careless with your words, or you are not thinking about the problem.

Comment: If **two** keys make a distinct unique key, and you made a **lookup by one key only**, then there are two possibilities: **1. You can get more than one result from the cache**, or **2. Your two keys are actually correlated and only one of them is actually enough.**

Comment: You are not thinking about the math. If key(n1,n2) = key(n1,sn3) = key(n2,sn3), then *all numbers will yield the same key!*

Comment: This will be possible only if you a correlation between string key and integer key. I don't think you have a control over "mykey" or `1`. If you could generate the id based on the string "mykey" then this is possible. Could you use the hash of the string itself as the id? Or else as suggested by m3tikn0b, maintain a separate dictionary where a key "mykey" will yield you `1`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is another approachm without XOR:

To generate a unique key x from 2 integers (a,b) and be able to find (a,b) from this key you can proceed as below:

**generate x from a and b :**

```
x = (2**a).(3**b) //(** means power)
```

there is a unique decompostion of x since 2 and 3 are prime numbers

**Then to get a  and b from x ;**

```
 divide x by 2 until you don't get an integer => number of division =a
 divide x by 3 until you don't get an integer => number of division =b
```

**Example of code (in python sorry I don't know C# well) :**

```
>>> def keyGenerator(a,b):
    return (2**a)*(3**b)

>>> def findNumbersFromKey(x):
    a=0
    b=0
    while(x%2 ==0):
        a+=1
        x/=2
    while(x%3 == 0):
        b+=1
        x/=3
    return a,b

>>> keyGenerator(5,4)
2592
>>> findNumbersFromKey(2592)
(5, 4)
>>> keyGenerator(25,14)
160489808068608L
>>> findNumbersFromKey(160489808068608L)
(25, 14)
```

Comment: Actually, what OP asked is how to get *x* from *a*, without knowing *b*. That's impossible, if *x* is expected to be unique for all combinations of *a* and *b*.

Comment: @Nazar I added an example of code in Python. You can try to translate it in C# and use it.

Comment: +1 to Groo, this answer is NOT a solution to what the OP wants.

Comment: @Groo. Yes you're right. I knew it wasn't the answer, be as you said what the OP wanted was impossible.

Comment: -1 for an answer that won't help OP. If there is no answer for an impossible job, answer that than a not-related answer.

Comment: problem is: if a and b are large values say a=10000 and b=5000 the computation of x may not be possible on normal computer

Answer (score 2):

key(a,b) := a XOR b is not unique at all as for example key(8,7) = 15 = key(12,3).

Assuming that your pairs (a,b) are values in the ranges 0 <= a < N and 0 <= b < M you could assign key(a,b) := a + b * N which is unique and in the range 0 <= key(a,b) < M*N.

I don't understand what you mean with *"But then I need to retrieve this unique key by using one of those numbers (37 or 8)."*. Do you want to be able to compute key(37,8) given only 37 as input? This would be impossible. How do you want to distinguish between key(37,8) and key(37,1234) given only 37 as input?

---

Update:

As noted before, if both keys are independent (i.e. neither of them can be computed efficiently from the other one) you cannot do this "compute the unique key from only one identifier" stuff.

To solve your problem I would suggest the following, based on the information you gave and assuming that both identifiers are known when Add() is called and that either identifier on its own is sufficient to uniquely identify each object:

Add a "Hashtable aliasTable" member to "Cache". When "Cache.Add(strID, intID, obj)" is called, use "intID" as the unique key. Additionally, let "aliasTable[strID] = intID". On a "Cache.Get(intID)" just use "intID" as unique key. On "Cache.Get(strID)" retrieve the unique key via "intID = aliasTable[strID]".

If you do the cache lookup more often via strID than intID, then use that as unique key and use aliasTable the other way round (mapping intID to strID).

Comment: Thanks it looks like one of the proper solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

How unique is unique? XORing two numbers is hardly a great method for generating unique numbers.

That said, for your specific example, given one input number and your key, then XORing those two together will give the second key.

a XOR b = c
c XOR b = a

Comment: This wont help OP anyway sadly. He will have to do `cache.Get("mykey")` or `cache.Get(1)`. Since those two numbers (hash of "mykey") are not correlated, its impossible to get the right key from "mykey" next time. In your example, when only provided with `b`, he wont have `a` to get `c`, in short..

Answer (score 0):

Just intersperse the two numbers. E.g. if you have a=1234 and b=99 :

```
a =   1 2 3 4 
b =      9 9 
key = 1029394
```

Note that the key is much smaller than in Ricky's proposal.

Comment: +1...aha! I kind of new that it was pretty easy just to mix the 2 numbers when I posted my answer, but I found my method more elegant so I decided to stick with it :D!

Comment: @nawfal: I tried to make the best out of the question (before the edit), which wasn't easy. Downvoting is so much easier than answering, isn't it?

Comment: @Landei no offense, but OP plainly asked something impossible (to my belief) right away. Now can you explain how your answer is going to help him somehow for the question given?

Comment: @nawfal: In that case I try to give the (in my opinion) closest possible solution, which hopefully guides the OP in the right direction. At least this can lead to a clarification by the OP (as here), which a simple "nope, impossible" won't do.

Comment: @Landei this is not a solution, dont call it so. A solution should deal with fixing the problem, or provide a workaround, or at least guide OP to right direction. While you claim you do so, did you really do? Is there anywhere in your answer you have mentioned "its impossible" ? Instead you wrote "Just do this" **which will only confuse OP** instead of guiding him. What you have provided is a "solution to a related problem". At best that should be a comment. There are threads on SO which demand your answer, you could have answered there and posted a link to it as a comment, at best.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the object twice, once with each key.  Then it can be retrieve with either key.  If you need the ability to delete items from the cache, then you will want to delete both references.  To facilitate that, you could store both keys in the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a unique key just concatenate the two unique numbers.

In my case I was needed to create a unique `room_id` for `socket.io` from the mobile numbers of two user.

In this way

```
key(n1,n2) != key(n1,sn3) != key(n2,sn3)
```